# How to reuse Django Model Form with changed labels?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, modelform

Inside a Django app I have a Person model that I want to use in a form to capture both student and teacher data. The fields are identical in both forms, but the labels should be different. How can I change the labels before passing the form to the template?

The class for the form with default labels for student_form:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
        labels = {
            'first_name': label("Student's Name"),
            'last_name': label("Student's Surname")
        }
```

I tried to change the labels attributes as per below, but Django says that ProfileForm has no attribute 'labels'.

```
def add_profile(request):

    teacher_form = ProfileForm(prefix = 'teacher')
    teacher_form.labels['first_name'] = label("Teacher's Name")
    teacher_form.labels['last_name'] = label("Teacher's Surname")

    return render(request, "school/add_profile.html", {
        "profileform" : teacher_form
    })
```

Is there a way to access the Meta class to change its attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the labels like this:

```
teacher_form.fields['first_name'].label = "Teacher's Name"
teacher_form.fields['last_name'].label = "Teacher's Surname"
```